# Python Decorator return value if condition met otherwise return function

Tags: python, decorator

I am looking to create a simple python decorator but I am not sure I am implementing it the most efficient way. The function I am decorating returns a car registration, but I want to be able to always return a test registration.

The class method I am decorating signature is:

`def get_car_registration(self, car_details)`

This is my current attempt of the decorator. Is there a more efficient way to do it.

```
from functools import wraps


def mock_registration(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        pargs = list(args)
        class_obj = pargs[0]
        car_details = pargs[1]
        if class_obj.test and car_details.car_name.startswith('test_demo'):
            return 0
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
z
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs in code-review

Comment: migrate to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this decorates only one function, the decorator is pretty much unnecessary and you can hard-code it into the function

Comment: It will decorate a lot of functions but all with the same signature.

Comment: The decorator is fine, except that you don't need to convert args to a list. But whether you should be using a decorator at all depends on the wider context. It sounds like maybe you should be using `unittest.mock`.

Comment: @gold_cy While this may be on-topic on CR in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ OP said _It seems to work but would like opinions on if this is the best way to do it_ which means he would like a code review. for me that is enough to close this question as off topic as it belongs in code review. thanks

Comment: @AlexHall We want users of our API to be able to trigger certain responses based on inputs so I don't think unittest would work in this case

Comment: @gold_cy I agree that it can be migrated - please see [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) (and _please read_ that post from my first comment as well) - it should help explain my point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the signature is known in advance, you should use it. [Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python):

```
def mock_registration(func):    
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(obj, car_details):
        if obj.test and car_details.car_name.startswith('test_demo'):
            return 0
        return func(obj, car_details)
    return wrapper
```

If your same-signature functions return different things you might decide to make a parametrizable decorator to pass different default return values:

```
def mock_registration(default=0):
    def decorator(func):        
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(obj, car_details):
            if obj.test and car_details.car_name.startswith('test_demo'):
                return default
            return func(obj, car_details)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

and decorate the method:

```
@mock_registration()
def get_car_registration(self, car_details):
    # ....
```